# file_object.read() evaluates to empty string in python 3

Tags: python

So, I am creating an app that needs to make use of files in python. I watched 10000 youtube videos, and I got this from what I watched

```
with open(str(fileName)) as foil:          # to read
    notes = foil.read().splitlines()

with open("notes.txt", "a") as foil:       # to add
    print(toAdd, file=foil)
```

But when I do `print(notes.splitlines()[0])`, My program always prints an empty string.

I did a check to change it to something if it is blank

```
if notes.splitLines()[0] == "": notes = "The note was empty"
```

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance to anybody that awnsers.

PS: Where do these files go? Do I need to replace "notes.txt" with a file path for it to work?

PPS: There is no syntax errors in my program. If there is one in my code in this post, I simply got it wrong when typing it into this post.

Comment: `notes` is a list, so as written, `print(notes.splitLines()[0])` will always error(its also `splitlines`, no caps, which will also cause an error). Please make sure your problem is reproducible by others

Comment: @BradSolomon I just wrote the case wrong when Reproducing the code into the post. It is correct within the actual program. Also, I thought that when I append to the file if there is no file detected then there will be one created.

Comment: @SuperStormer I have the case correct in the program. I just wrote it wrong in the post.

Comment: Please look at the guidelines for making a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We should be able to copy the code in your question, paste it into a fresh Python file, run it, and get the same output or error as you describe. You can test this ahead of time by doing so yourself.

Comment: @CrazyChucky Thanks, I didn't realize. I will keep that in mind in my next post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code raises an exception (AttributeError) for me. In general, `notes` will be a list of the lines in your source file - if the source file is empty, this should also raise an error as the list index will be out of range.

In general, your filename needs to be the path that your program needs to find the file. If they are in the same directory, something like 'file.txt' will be enough. If not, you will have to provide the full path, or it will result in a FileNotFoundError. Hope this clears up your questions.